# Filter or Jump to Value in Combo Box

Tags: ms-access, filter, combobox, ms-access-2016

I am trying to make my combo box more user friendly, since it contains about 300+ companies. I am trying to find a way where a user can press a letter like "z" and it will jump down the the first z. I have not really seen a way to do this and when I search I find a lot of info about filtering list boxes.

If that isn't do able, is there a way to use queries and re-query on change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the property sheet for the combobox, set *AutoComplete* to True.

Comment: unfortunately I am not seeing an AutoComplete under any of the tabs in the property sheet. Is there a chance it was named something else or is there something in the Database Options I need to select?

Comment: It is at tab Data, bottom.

Comment: Gustav - there is no 'Autocomplete' in access 2016 desktop as far as I can see.

Comment: @LeasMaps: There is, but it is labelled [AutoExpand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845130.aspx)